# How to count only specific row's column value in R

Tags: r

I have to count total_buy/total sell of only column "A to D"......
it should not contain column "E to H"

[image]

Comment: Pls use data not pictures. Check out `?dput`.

Comment: @harry, on SO, posting samples in images is NOT encouraged, so please proper samples of input and output in code tags and let us know then.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid inserting of pictures and check the solution:

```
dummy<-data.frame(A=sample(c("buy","sell"),100,replace = T),
           B=sample(c("buy","sell"),100,replace = T),
           C=sample(c("buy","sell"),100,replace = T),
           D=sample(c("buy","sell"),100,replace = T),
           E=sample(c("buy","sell"),100,replace = T),
           G=sample(c("buy","sell"),100,replace = T))

head(dummy)

     A    B    C    D    E    G
1  buy  buy sell sell  buy  buy
2  buy  buy  buy  buy  buy  buy
3  buy sell  buy  buy sell  buy
4 sell  buy  buy sell  buy sell
5 sell sell sell sell sell sell
6 sell sell  buy sell sell sell
```

Now apply the function with `sapply` on selected columns from 1:4 i.e., A to D

```
sapply(dummy[1:4], function(x) table((x)))
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
      A  B  C  D
buy  50 53 53 51
sell 50 47 47 49
```